# Como hacer que todas mis imágenes tengan las mismas dimensiones

Tags: python

estoy programando una IA para reconocer y clasificar imágenes, pero a la hora de descargar los datos, me salta el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (374,500,3) into shape (280,300,3)
```

mi código para cargar los datos es el siguiente:

```
train_dir = './gatos' 
print('total de imágenes:', len( os.listdir(train_dir)))

def load_data():
  filelist = os.listdir(train_dir)

  num_images = len(filelist)
  x_train = np.zeros((num_images, 280, 300, 3)) 
  
  for i, fname in enumerate(filelist):
    if fname != '.DS_Store':
      imagen = imread(os.path.join(train_dir, fname))
      x_train[i,:] = (imagen - 127.5) / 127.5
  
  return x_train


x_train = load_data()
print('cargando imágenes...')
print(x_train.shape)
```

pero no puedo cargar los datos, ya que hay algunos que tienen unas dimensiones distintas, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que todas las imágenes estuviesen con las mismas dimensiones? No logro encontrar nada y tengo bastantes imágenes con distintas dimensiones, si alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto se lo agradecería mucho. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas hacer una interpolación con alguna librería gráfica, por ejemplo opencv o pillow, puede ser hacia arriba (más resolución) o hacia abajo (menor), el otro problema es el aspecto, ¿qué se hace con una imagen rectangular que quieras ajustar a una imagen más cuadrada?

Comment: Buenas, me gustaría saber como hacer que todas las imágenes tengan la misma dimensión, si pudieses pasarme un trozo de código o un enlace con ayuda sobre esto. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Que habría que hacer si tienes una imagen de 500x300 que deberías "bajar" a 280 x 300? un resize común haría que aparezca un gato mucho más "flaco" que el original, eso tal vez complique tus algoritmos posteriores.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho ese resize sería ilógico, lo ideal es usar un múltiplo común  en ambos tamaños por ejemplo de 500 x 300 a 167x100

Comment: entonces para este error:  could not broadcast input array from shape (4000,6000,3) into shape (128,128,3) que valores debería de poner en el reshape??

Comment: @tincopasan, esta claro que modificar el "aspect ratio" es algo, que al menos el sentido común diría que está mal, por eso lo señalo, por que es lo que se está planteando en esta pregunta. Bien, entonces pregunto ¿que se debe hacer con imágenes que no respetan la proporción final?

Answer (score 1):

quizá podrías usar la biblioteca Pillow, por ejemplo:

```
from PIL import Image
```

la debes tener insatalada, ej:
en la cmd : pip install Pillow

```
imagen = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
```

cargas la imagen

```
reducida = imagen.resize((125, 160))
```

le asignas el tamaño que necesites

Obtenes la imagen con el tamaño indicado

```
reducida.save("reducida.jpg")
```

esto si la querés guardar con el nuevo tamaño
Guardar imagen obtenida con el formato JPEG

Comment: ¿Y para hacer esto con múltiples imágenes? Es decir, tengo en una carpeta 100 imágenes y quiero tener las 100 imágenes al mismo tamaño

Comment: con un bucle! lees los nombres del directorio y los usas como variable

Comment: ¿Y para tratarlo como numpy array? es decir, necesito tener una variable que tenga guardado todos los valores de las imágenes para poder pasarlos a mi red neuronal